# Problem running a C script with external head file in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, cs50

I am trying to solve a problem set from cs50's course, however, when I try to run the following code on my desktop version of Visual Studio Code, I get a compilation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cs50.h"


// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }
    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i=0;i<candidate_count;i++){
        if(!strcmp(name,candidates[i].name)){
            candidates[i].votes +=1;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    int max=0;
    string max_name = "";
    for (int i=0;i<candidate_count;i++){
        if(max<candidates[i].votes){
            max = candidates[i].votes;
            strcpy(max_name,candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<candidate_count;i++){
        if(candidates[i].votes==max){
            printf("%s\n",candidates[i].name);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Following Error shows up at the terminal;

```
*  Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file 

Starting build...
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g D:\Work\C-Language\Plurality.c -o D:\Work\C-Language\Plurality.exe 
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccrzNxos.o: in function `main':
D:/Work/C-Language/Plurality.c:49: undefined reference to `get_int'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Work/C-Language/Plurality.c:53: undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
```

I have set up my Visual Studio Code for C/C++ using the following link;
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

The Terminal shows that the program can not compile the external header file simultaneously, can you please guide me through this because it is my first time using VS Code for C/C++, previously I used to work on Dev C++, if there is some specific config: you would want to suggest for using VS Code for C/C++ programs, it will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: According to the exposed error message, it's not the header which is your problem but the linker. You probably have to add a library dependency for `get_int` and `get_string`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need to add `cs50.c` to the project. That source file contains the definitions for the missing functions.

Comment: cs50.c is already in the same directory as plurality.c

Answer (score 0):

Add link to cs50 library to compiling command.
How to do this is explained in notes and video for week 2.
First topic is about compiling.

Also it is more informative when you put in quotes what command you enter when try to compile, not only output.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I have tried that way but still It shows an Error on argument " -lcs50 " that can not find cs50: no file or directory, however when I try -l"D:\Work\C-Language\Plurality\cs50" it says invalid argument, can you please tell me what's the correct syntax to add full path to the folder, while I am doing this both the program "Plurality.c , cs50.c and cs50.h " are in the same folder.